# Find range of cells, when given 2 Dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with numbers from 1 to 10. (Starting from D2 to M2)

Suppose in **A1** there is **03/09/2019**

AND in **B1** there is **06/09/2019**

AND in **C1** there is **Hello**

In **COLUMN A** I have a multiple series of words starting from **A3 to A10**

Here is an Example of the Excel Table

[image]

What I would like to do is: **Search** for the word **Student** in **Column A**, when I find it, get the numbers from **A1 --> 3**
 and **A2 --> 6** and write the word **Hello that is in C1** in the cells that go to 3 to 6 in the row of the finded word **Student**

So my output would be like:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
Dim Cell As Range
Columns("A:A").Select 
Set Cell = Selection.Find(What:="Student", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Word not found"

Else
    MsgBox "Word found"
End If
```

Basically I can find the word **Student** but don't know how to write the word **Hello** in the cells between **3 to 6**

Comment: You `Range.Find` is looking in `xlFormulas`. This should be values most likely. Also, I would remove the `Columns("A:A").Select` and qualify that range explicitly.

Comment: Yeah didn't noticed that... I Select the whole Column Because maybe there could be more words that just these ones... So basically I don't know the real range

Comment: You can explicitly define the range by looking for the last used row from the bottom up and then search in that range rather the entire column. This isn't your problem - just more of a best practice thing

Comment: The using of the whole column is not the problem.  Skip the `.Select` line and reference it directly in the `Find()` line: `Set Cell =Columns("A:A").Find....`

Comment: @urdearboy you make it so easy :) .. by the way, that would be really great but unfortunatelly my code knowledge is really basic...

Comment: Well updating your search to look in values and updating with @ScottCraner advise should fix that problem. After, you can use a combination of `Offsets` to find the columns. Since your table starts at column D and your found value is column A, you will want to offset 5 columns for `3` and 8 columns for `6`.

Comment: Use two more Finds to find where the `Day(Range("A1"))` is found in `Row("2:2")`

Comment: Then you will have the row and the column to use in `Cells()`

Comment: @urdearboy just trying to use something about which the OP has already demonstrated knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few notes regarding the code below (not tested!).

1)  Always try use worksheet qualifiers when working with VBA. This will allow for cleaner code with less room for unnecessary errors

2)  When using `.Find` method I use `LookAt:=xlWhole` because if you do not explicitly define this your code will use the last known method that you would have used in Excel. Again, explicit definition leaves less room for error.

3)  Try include error handling when you code. This provides “break points” for easier debugging in the future.

4) You can make the below much more dynamic that it currently is. But I'll leave that up to you to learn how to do!

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SearchAndBuild()

    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim lDayOne As Long, lDayTwo As Long
    Dim lColOne As Long, lColTwo As Long
    Dim sHello As String
    Dim wsS1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long


    'set the worksheet object
    Set wsS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'store variables
    lDayOne = Day(wsS1.Range("A1").Value)
    lDayTwo = Day(wsS1.Range("B1").Value)
    sHello = wsS1.Range("C1").Value

    'find the student first
    Set rSearch = wsS1.Range("A:A").Find(What:="Student", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    'error handling
    If rSearch Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, could not find Student."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'now loop forwards to find first date and second date - store column naumbers
    'adjust these limits where necessary - can make dynamic
    For i = 4 To 13
        If wsS1.Cells(2, i).Value = lDayOne Then
            lColOne = i
        End If
        If wsS1.Cells(2, i).Value = lDayTwo Then
            lColTwo = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'now merge the range
    wsS1.Range(wsS1.Cells(rSearch.Row, lColOne), wsS1.Cells(rSearch.Row, lColTwo)).Merge

    'set the vvalue
    wsS1.Cells(rSearch.Row, lColOne).Value = sHello

End Sub
```

This is just one way to approach the problem. Hopefully this helps your understanding!

Comment: Wow, that is a very good exaplanation! I will take note, because I never handle errors... @Dean you are a PROFESSOR

Comment: good call on the `Day` function. Stealing since it's much more intuitive :) (+1)

Comment: @ChangeWorld I am glad I could help. If this is the answer you are looking for, please do not forget to mark as answer to close the ticket. :)

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop here - just find your value and parse the dates. Assuming your value to be found exists in `Column A` and your table starts in `Column D`, there is clear relationship between the columns which is `Day(date) + 3`.

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, Found As Range
Dim date_a As Long, date_b As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Found = ws.Range("A2:A" & lr).Find("Student", LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    date_a = Day(Range("A1")) + 3
    date_b = Day(Range("B1")) + 3

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(Found.Row, date_a), ws.Cells(Found.Row, date_b))
        .Merge
        .Value = ws.Range("C1")
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "Value 'Student' Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Never tought of splitting a date to get the day in index 0, pretty clever

Comment: lol @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I ended up changing it to `Day` function since i liked that better. I suppose the upside to the split is that it will also work on strings that are masquerading as dates.

Comment: I mosly like code without loop because I really hate it, nice approach, unfortnatelly I have accepted @Dean...

Comment: @ChangeWorld he had a good solution. No need to apologize here lol. You picked the answer for you, but this answer may help someone else down the road who stumbles upon your question :) All have merits

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this:

```
Dim ThisRow As Long

Dim FindWhat As String
FindWhat = "Student"

Dim MyStart As Byte
Dim MyEnd As Byte

MyStart = Day(Range("A1").Value) + 3 'we add +3 because starting 1 is in the fourth column
MyEnd = Day(Range("B1").Value) + 3 'we add +3 because starting 1 is in the fourth column

Dim SearchRange As Range
Set SearchRange = Range("A3:A10") 'range of values

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    'we first if the value exists with a count.
    If .CountIf(SearchRange, FindWhat) > 0 Then 'it means findwhat exists
        ThisRow = .Match(FindWhat, Range("A:A"), 0) 'we find row number of value

        Range(Cells(ThisRow, MyStart), Cells(ThisRow, MyEnd)).Value = Range("C1").Value
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Range(Cells(ThisRow, MyStart), Cells(ThisRow, MyEnd)).Merge
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Value 'Student' Not Found"
    End If
End With
```

Note I've used worksheets function COUNTIF and MATCH. MATCH will find the position of an element in a range, so if you check the whole column, it will tell you the row number. But if it finds nothing, it will rise an error. Easy way to avoid that is, first, counting if the value exists in that range with COUNTIF, and if it does, then you can use MATCH safely

Also, note that because we are using MATCH, this function only finds first coincidence, so if your list of values in column A got duplicates, this method won't work for you!.

[image]